# Add active class to submenu on click in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular5

I have created a nested menu in Angular 4. I am facing problem with active class. Here is my code.

[My code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sccux2)

I am able to add active class to main link but what should I do to add active class to submenu based on click. Please help

Comment: Clicking on second menu and third menu shows the submenu...then what you want?

Comment: On click of submenu clicked submenu should be active. what should I do for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an object to store what is selected for `main` link and `sub` link and then apply the class accordingly.

For example, you may pass `main` as an argument to tell that it is a main link and check `isActive` accordingly for `main` itself.

```
(click)="select('main', n.name);" [ngClass]="{active: isActive('main', n.name)}"
```

Similarly, it can be done for the `sub` link.

Your functions could be as follows:-

```
  select(type, item, $event) {
    this.selected[type] = (this.selected[type] === item ? null : item);
    $event ? $event.stopPropagation() : null;
  }
  isActive(type, item) {
    return this.selected[type] === item;
  }
```

You may stop propagation when selecting the sub link which is optional, I suppose (Kindly test for your use case).

Please check the code below:-

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7b7cwd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank u so much @Ankit :)

Comment: Glad that it helped. :)

Comment: There is one problem. Please check in this condition. click on one sub menu the open second main menu.

Comment: That is because both sub menus have the same value as `Sub Menu 1`. Kindly try changing the values for the sub menus. I have changed it in the example for you. Please check now. You need to pass something else to identify it easily and correctly.

Comment: Hi @Ankit can you  please help me, I don't want router link if menu have sub menu and on 1st time page load one menu should be active. can u please help

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar You may use `router.navigate` function to decide if you need to navigate. For more info on how to use, pls visit https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component. You may also choose to use `*ngIf` to either render an anchor tag or span tag. To choose one menu on page load, you may pass a value to your component or set it in `ngOnInit` function.